# Own Laravel php artisan command in console.php

Tags: command-line, laravel-5.4, laravel-routing

I have a file in `app/Console/Commands/SendEmail.php` with this content:

```
<?php
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class SendEmail extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'send_email';
    protected $description = 'Command description';
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function handle()
    {
        echo "hello wordl\n";
    }
}
```

I added these lines into `routes/console.php`:

```
use App\Console\Commands\SendEmail;
Artisan::command('send_email', function() { });
```

And the question is: what I need to write into the `routes/console.php` file to run this command?

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: still not yet...

Comment: Yes have fix this. The issue was i have called the url() on config/app.php file. When i remove this the artisan commands works smoothly